# how to change existing environment variables in my openshift application?

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, openshift

I have an application hosted on  openshift , with a mysql database, now as per features, they have mysql username, password in env variables, but i want to change the evn variable for mysql password as they show the password, as soon as we login, is there any way to change, i googled a lot, but links were either 404 or the answers were pointing to 404 links. would appropriate an answer as soon as possible...here are some of the links which i tried [link one](https://forums.openshift.com/forgot-the-mysql-password-how-modify-it) [link two](https://forums.openshift.com/changing-db-admin-password-how-to-change-env-as-well) [and 404 link](https://blog.openshift.com/new-openshift-release-may-15-2012-community-code-custom-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rhc env set` command to add/update your environment variables, but be careful as those env variables can be used within your application, and changing them can cause login issues with your database etc

https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html